# How do I consecutively close, then open a new panel (if one is active to begin with) for multiple panel views overlayed on the same view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI application where users can create groups for other members, and therefore become the admin of that group. As admin, they have access to other controls and abilities, in the form of a custom toolbar of icons at the top of the group's page view. Those being:

- Settings / Admin tools
- Manage members
- Post / manage content

Pressing each of these control icons triggers its respective panel (or drawer I think its more commonly called), a half sheet overlay with view content.

The main issue I'm having is that if one of these panels is currently open, and I press on another panel control icon, the panel view content instantly changes. What I'd like to happen is for the panel to close, then re-open the new panel. The animation to open/close (`.spring()`) is there but I'm unsure how to consecutively do these view operations.

I thought of using a `Timer` to wait for view to close, but that feels sloppy. I feel there is a consecutive view modifier/operation to use more appropriately, but I'm unaware of it.

Also I feel some of my code is redundant and inefficient, so if anyone has suggestions there I'd be happy to hear them.

```
struct GroupPage: View {

    // The enum and @State vars here I feel could be executed alot better and consolidated somehow
    enum ActivePanel {
        case add
        case settings
        case member
        case none
    }

    @State var addMode: OUI.PanelMode = .none
    @State var settingsMode: OUI.PanelMode = .none
    @State var memberMode: OUI.PanelMode = .none
    @State var activePanel: ActivePanel = .none
    
    @ObservedObject var manager: GroupViewModel
    init(_ manager: GroupViewModel) { self.manager = manager }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Group page content here
            adminControls
            
            // Panels are "present" but in closed state
            addPanel
            settingsPanel
            memberPanel
        }
    }

    var adminControls: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { showPanel(.member)}) {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
                Button(action: { showPanel(.settings)}) {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
                Button(action: { showPanel(.add)}) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
    }
    
    var addPanel: some View {
        OUI.Panel($addMode) {
            // Add / manage posts view content
        }
    }
    
    var settingsPanel: some View {
        OUI.Panel($settingsMode) {
            // Settings view content
        }
    }
    
    var memberPanel: some View {
        OUI.Panel($memberMode) {
            // Member management view content
        }
    }
    
    private func showPanel(_ mode: ActivePanel) {

        // closePanel here I would like to visually close the panel, then reopen it back-to-back in switch statements below
        closePanel()

        // if statements close the panel altogether if already active
        switch mode {
        case .add:
            if addMode == .half { addMode = .none }
            else { addMode = .half }
            
        case .settings:
            if settingsMode == .half { settingsMode = .none }
            else { settingsMode = .half }
            
        case .member:
            if memberMode == .half { memberMode = .none }
            else { memberMode = .half }
            
        case .none:
            closePanel() // Redundant probably
        }
    }
    
    private func closePanel() {
        addMode = .none
        settingsMode = .none
        memberMode = .none
        activePanel = .none
    }
}

// OUI (a typealias) is my app's custom UI class and below is the Panel code
// No initializers or anything else that is needed to be known for OUI

// Execution for Panel code I believe is very rough here too and could be done much better
// Conceptually I mean, not visually (will fix visuals later but wanted to get the functionality first)
// Mostly replicated from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2gFel5Bins&t=1s&ab_channel=azamsharp
// Tweaked for my use case which is where I think I overcomplicated the code but could be wrong

extension OUI {

    enum PanelMode: CaseIterable {
        case none
        case quarter
        case half
        case threequarters
        case full
        case responsive // Tightens the view as much as possible
    }
    
    struct Panel<Content: View>: View {
        var mode: Binding<PanelMode>
        var content: () -> Content
        let deviceHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        
        init(_ mode: Binding<PanelMode>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
            self.mode = mode
            self.content = content
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            Group {
                if mode.wrappedValue == .responsive {
                    responsiveBody
                } else if mode.wrappedValue == .half || mode.wrappedValue == .quarter {
                    halfQuarterBody
                } else {
                    fullBody
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring())
        }
        
        var panelTemplate: some View {
            Color.offBlack
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: mode.wrappedValue == .responsive ? nil : .infinity)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .border(Color.blue)
                
        }
        
        var fullBody: some View {
            panelTemplate
                .overlay {
                    content()
                        .padding()
                }
                .offset(y: calculateOffset())
                
        }
        
        var halfQuarterBody: some View {
            panelTemplate
                .overlay {
                    VStack {
                        content()
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .offset(y: calculateOffset())
            
        }
        
        var responsiveBody: some View {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                content()
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background { panelTemplate }
            }
        }
    
        private func calculateOffset() -> CGFloat {
            switch mode.wrappedValue {
            case .none:
                return deviceHeight

            case .quarter:
                return (3/4) * deviceHeight

            case .half:
                return (1/2) * deviceHeight

            case .threequarters:
                return (1/4) * deviceHeight

            case .full:
                return 0

            case .dynamic:
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are thinking of the user levels as part of your UI. That really needs to be your model. The enum is on the right track, but why not an enum of your actual user levels. I would think that you would model a person, and then as part of your model, that person has a user level. You should also google access control management.

Comment: @Yrb So the actual code is pretty long and obviously I didn't wanna include it all. But yeah I have is set up that way and the GroupViewModel handles all that so that adminControls is only accessible by the admin. I just didn't think it was relevant to include for this question.

Comment: My comment was really more of a "You are asking a model question, not an implementation question". But in the end, there are lots of resources for what you are looking for which is access control management.